# Bug after install admin product manager can not get into admin magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento

After installing extension "Advanced Admin Products Manager" by Iksanika face a probles I am unable to get into admin error "Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /home/cctvdvrs/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php on line 313 "

please help me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have Magento `Compilation` enabled. Try after disabling it from backend.

[image]